# Php Admin Panel displays Edit post form below the footer

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, admin

So I made this Awesome website following a CMS tutorial for Php,
I am making this website for a school and this is my first ever dynamic website.
So I created an admin panel which looks like this.

[Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apWNr.jpg)

Looks cool right?
Actually I made a basic admin panel following the tutorial and now I've migrated the code to an awesome Admin panel theme and I've moved my code to admin2 now.
When I click on view post, it puts a variable "view" in Get global array.

```
<a href="index.php?view=view">
```

This view variable has a code in the same index.php page.

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['view'])){   
     //My form and loop to get data from database and display here
}
        ?>
```

But for editing a post, I have a seperate file which catches the following code from index.php

```
<td><a href= "edit.php?edit=<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</a></td>
```

This is a table data present in the same if(isset) condition I've mentioned above.

In my edit.php file, I have code to update the data of the same table that a user has clicked on.

```
<?php
include 'index.php';
//Update code and form
?>
```

Now my page is displayed like this.

[AdminPanel display problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYley.jpg)

I can see that my table is displayed below the footer area because I'm putting index in it right above this form code.
What can I do to add this code to the right empty area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your index.php page

```
//Check for edit same place as you are checking view
<?php if (isset($_GET['edit'])){   
     include 'edit.php?edit='.$_GET['edit'];
}
        ?>
```

Comment: And how shall I change this line

Comment: <td><a href= "edit.php?edit=<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</a></td>

Comment: <td><a href= "index.php?edit=<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</a></td>

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved, after a lots of efforts.

Comment: I just added 
<?php 
 if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
  include 'edit.php'; 
 }
?>
in the index.php
and data in td had carried post id
<a href= "index.php?edit=<?php echo $id;?>
and I had seperate file edit.php which get these things from index and gets included in index.php.
I'm going to accept your answer.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Sorry my reputation is below 15 yet,
How can I increase reputation here?